# eCharts Seleccionar xAxis de serie

Tags: javascript, chart.js, gráficas

No puedo encontrar la manera de indicarle a la serie en qué punto del eje X dibujarse,
La barra "Draw in Axis2" se dibuja en el "axis1".

**Actual:**

[image: Actual]

**Esperado:**

[image: Esperado]

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfbp5j9z/1/**

```js
 // 基于准备好的dom，初始化echarts实例
        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

var lightBlue = {
    type: 'linear',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    x2: 0,
    y2: 1,
    colorStops: [{
        offset: 0,
        color: 'rgba(1, 50, 67, 1)' // 0% 处的颜色
    }, {
        offset: 1,
        color: 'rgba(1, 50, 67, 0.5)' // 100% 处的颜色
    }],
    globalCoord: false // 缺省为 false
}
var gradientGreen = {
    type: 'linear',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    x2: 0,
    y2: 1,
    colorStops: [{
        offset: 0,
        color: 'rgba(1, 140, 50, 1)' // 0% 处的颜色
    }, {
        offset: 1,
        color: 'rgba(1, 140, 50, 0.5)' // 100% 处的颜色
    }],
    globalCoord: false // 缺省为 false
}


var option = {
    "title": {
        "text": "Test", 
        "x": "center"
    }, 
    "tooltip": {
        "trigger": "axis", 
        "axisPointer": {
            "type": "shadow"
        },
    }, 
    "grid": {
        "borderWidth": 0, 
        "y2": 120
    }, 
    "legend": {
         data: ['axis1', 'axis2'],
    }, 
    "toolbox": {
        "show": true
    }, 
    "calculable": true, 
    "xAxis":
             
        {
            "data": ["axis1","axis2"],
            "type": "category", 
            "splitLine": {
                "show": true
            }, 
            "axisTick": {
                "show": false
            },
            "splitArea": {
                "show": false
            }, 

       
    }, 
    "yAxis": 
        {
            "axisLine": {"show": true}, 
            "axisTick": {"show": true}, 
        },
   
    "series": [
{
            "name": "test1", 
            "type": "bar", 
        
            "itemStyle": {
                "normal": {
                    "color": gradientGreen,
                    "label": {
                        "show": true, 
                        "textStyle": {
                            "fontFamily":"monospace",
                            "fontSize":"20",
                            "color": "white",
                        }, 
                        "position": "inside",
                      formatter : function(params) {
                                     return 'Test' 
                                             }
                   }
                }
            }, 
            "data": [30]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "test2", 
            "type": "bar", 
            "itemStyle": {
                "normal": {
                    "color": lightBlue,
                    "label": {
                        "show": true, 
                        "textStyle": {
                            "fontFamily":"monospace",
                            "fontSize":"20",
                            "color": "white",
                        }, 
                        "position": "inside",
                      formatter : function(params) {
                                     return 'Draw in' + '\n' + 'Axis 2' 
                                             }
                   }
                }
            }, 
            "data": [30]
        }, 
   
    ]
};

        // 使用刚指定的配置项和数据显示图表。
        myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts-en.common.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

no conosco muy bien la libreria pero testeando me di cuenta que espera 2 parametros por default si no los agrupa en la primera la solucion mas simple que vi es mandarle 2 en `data 30,0` y `0,30`

```js
 // 基于准备好的dom，初始化echarts实例
        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

var lightBlue = {
    type: 'linear',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    x2: 0,
    y2: 1,
    colorStops: [{
        offset: 0,
        color: 'rgba(1, 50, 67, 1)' // 0% 处的颜色
    }, {
        offset: 1,
        color: 'rgba(1, 50, 67, 0.5)' // 100% 处的颜色
    }],
    globalCoord: false // 缺省为 false
}
var gradientGreen = {
    type: 'linear',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    x2: 0,
    y2: 1,
    colorStops: [{
        offset: 0,
        color: 'rgba(1, 140, 50, 1)' // 0% 处的颜色
    }, {
        offset: 1,
        color: 'rgba(1, 140, 50, 0.5)' // 100% 处的颜色
    }],
    globalCoord: false // 缺省为 false
}


var option = {
    /*"title": {
        "text": "Test", 
        "x": "center"
    },*/ 
    "tooltip": {
        "trigger": "axis", 
        "axisPointer": {
            "type": "shadow"
        },
    }, 
    "grid": {
        "borderWidth": 0, 
        "y2": 120
    }, 
    "legend": {
         data: ['test1', 'test2'],
    }, 
    "toolbox": {
        "show": true
    }, 
    "calculable": true, 
    "xAxis":
             
        {
            "data": ["axis1","axis2"],
            "type": "category", 
            "splitLine": {
                "show": true
            }, 
            "axisTick": {
                "show": false
            },
            "splitArea": {
                "show": false
            }, 

       
    }, 
    "yAxis": 
        {
            "axisLine": {"show": true}, 
            "axisTick": {"show": true}, 
        },
   
    "series": [
{
            "name": "test1", 
            "type": "bar", 
        
            "itemStyle": {
                "normal": {
                    "color": gradientGreen,
                    "label": {
                        "show": true, 
                        "textStyle": {
                            "fontFamily":"monospace",
                            "fontSize":"20",
                            "color": "white",
                        }, 
                        "position": "inside",
                      formatter : function(params) {
                                     return 'Test' 
                                             }
                   }
                }
            }, 
            "data": [30,0]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "test2", 
            "type": "bar", 
            "itemStyle": {
                "normal": {
                    "color": lightBlue,
                    "label": {
                        "show": true, 
                        "textStyle": {
                            "fontFamily":"monospace",
                            "fontSize":"20",
                            "color": "white",
                        }, 
                        "position": "inside",
                      formatter : function(params) {
                                     return 'Draw in' + '\n' + 'Axis 2' 
                                             }
                   }
                }
            }, 
            "data": [0,30]
        }, 
   
    ]
};

        // 使用刚指定的配置项和数据显示图表。
        myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts-en.common.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```